# Write standalone React.PropTypes.any.isRequired

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

PropTypes are being removed from the main React library. All I need for my project is `React.PropTypes.any.isRequired` and nothing else.

Is it possible to write this validator as a standalone function so I can avoid adding a new dependency? What is React expecting from this function?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: @Sulthan Sorry I don't see how that's helpful. I've looked at the source but need some guidance to isolate what this underlying validator functions looks like. And like I said in my post my goal is to avoid the 'prop-types' dep.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html), the validator is nothing more than:

```
customProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
  if (!/matchme/.test(props[propName])) {
    return new Error(
      'Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' +
      ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
    );
  }
},
```

Therefore, if you check for `null`, that's everything you need to simulate `Any.isRequired`.

Comment: Thanks Sulthan, so if the validator doesn't throw an error it's valid? I doesn't need to return anything if valid?

Comment: @boom That seems to be the case.

Comment: what is the meaning of "!/matchme/.test(props[propName]"?

Answer (score 1):

isRequired checks to see if the prop is `undefined` or `null` and throws an error if either of those is matched. Refer to the source of isRequired here:
https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/factoryWithTypeCheckers.js#L191

Comment: I'm not using it to check types at all, I'm just using it to trigger context. Right now my lib has no deps outside of react and I'd like to keep it that way. Do you have a clearer definition of what logic I would be circumventing?

Comment: I think I got a little jumpy about that. Looks like it just builds a new Error which is what was mentioned in the above answer.